# Integration of multidimensional Gaussian

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics, distributions

How could the following integration of a 6-dimensional Gaussian be achieved? Are there some techniques? (MMA code below)

$$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }a \cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2} \left(z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2+z_4^2+z_5^2+z_6^2\right)}dx_6dx_5dx_4dx_3dx_2dx_1$$
with

$a =\sqrt{(z_1 z_5 - z_2 z_4)^2 + (z_3 z_4 - z_1 z_6)^2 + (z_2 z_6 - z_3 z_5)^2}
\\
z1 = p1 + x1
\\
z2 = p2 + x2
\\
z3 = p3 + x3 
\\
z4 = p4 + x4 
\\
z5 = p5 + x5 
\\
z6 = p6 + x6 $

where $p_1$,...,$p_6$ are free variables.

MMA code:

```
z1 = p1 + x1; 
z2 = p2 + x2; 
z3 = p3 + x3; 
z4 = p4 + x4; 
z5 = p5 + x5; 
z6 = p6 + x6; 
a = Sqrt[(z1*z5 - z2*z4)^2 + (z3*z4 - z1*z6)^2 + (z2*z6 - z3*z5)^2]; 
Integrate[a*E^((-1/2)*(z1^2 + z2^2 + z3^2 + z4^2 + z5^2 + z6^2)), {x1, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x2, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x3, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  {x4, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x5, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x6, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Comment: How about if you try the two dimensional version... then the three... see where it fails?

Comment: Even integration in 1 dimension is not easy.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/445185/expectation-of-cross-product-of-normal-distributed-variables also asked by the OP.  It's a good question but just a duplicate.

Comment: Use Monte Carlo.